# What is the best design to integrate a button in orderedlist and use it to get orderedlist data using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, frontend, web-frontend

BACKGROUND:

I am getting grocery Item details from backend and I want to have a design to add each one of them to Cart on click of a button "Add To Cart". I am rendering the data as shown below, but cant move ahead.

javaScript Code :

```
function displayStoreInventory()
{
    var groceryStoreUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/groceryStore";
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        try
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var itemArray = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                var list = "<ol id='itemList'>";
                for(var i in itemArray)
                {
                    var l = "<ul>" + 
                        "<li>" + itemArray[i].brand + " : " + itemArray[i].category  + "</li>" +
                        "<li>" + "Price: " + itemArray[i].price + "</li>" +
                        **"<button class=btnAddToCart onclick=addToCart()>Add to Cart</button>**<br><br>" + 
                        "</ul>";
                    list += "<li>" + l + "</li><br><br>";
                }
                list += "</ol>";
                document.getElementById("idDisplayStore").innerHTML = list;
            }
        }
        catch(erMs)
        {
            document.getElementById("idDisplayStore").innerHTML = erMs;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", groceryStoreUrl, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhttp.send();
}
```

I have another function in javaScript for adding item to cart, which I need to implement and am stuck there.

```
function addToCart()
{
    /* Need to implement this. So that I can send that particular selected Item to backend to add to cart.*/
}
```

QUESTIONS:

1.On click of the button, only that item should be send to cart. I do not know how to access only that element, as in my design I have no way to know which button was clicked.

2.If anyone have a better design or link to a post explaining the same, please do mention.

PS: This is not a simple question to access data from an unorderd list in javascript. I want to know the best design followed in frontend development for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you should have different identificators for every product from back end ( they could be long numbers, string + numbers and etc) in your `JSON.parse(this.responseText)`

Then just apply that as a `data-product-id` for example to your Add to cart button.
Remove that inline onClick function from there, it is not good practice.

Then add eventListerner in your global javascript file for click for add to cart button and in it you will get current `data-product-id`. After you get this - you will know which exactly product is being clicked for adding to cart.

Then based on your back end logic you may need to send ajax request to the server with this id in order to let server know that this product is added to cart.

Let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: Thanks @Gessha. I have tried something like this "<button class=classicButton onclick=addToCart("+ (Number(productIndex) +")>Add to Cart</button>" and function addToCart(index){ //my code} . Is this encouraged in frontend web development

Comment: @Lazycoder_007 not actually. It is not good to add function which will be called in your markup.
Instead I would suggest to have something like `<button class=classicButton data-product-index="productIndex">Add to cart</button>` 
And then in your event handler for click to get the indexo f actual product from `data-product-index`